# I can't convert á€±á€”á€±á€” these character to String like Myanmar font

Tags: utf-8

I can't convert á€±á€”á€±á€” these character to String like Myanmar font
when i used
String ss =new String(rs.getString(i).getBytes("ISO-8859-15"),"utf8");
convert to ????
I want to convert it with my specified font
I used it with database

Answer (score 1):

There's too much string conversion going on there. When you do `rs.getString(i)` the database driver will interpret the bytes in the column as being in the database defined character set, before converting to Java's internal representation (UTF-16). The call to `getBytes` will then convert the string to a series of bytes in ISO-8859-15 and then you're interpreting those bytes at UTF-8. Phew!

So is the database storing the data in ISO-8859-15 or UTF-8? What's the encoding specification on the table? If you know exactly what they're stored as and want to avoid the database driver doing any string work, you can use this workaround:

```
String ss = new String( rs.getBytes( i ), "UTF-8" );  // Change UTF-8 to the encoding you know is in use
```

I hope some of that helps.